# Installing libmodbus in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, cmake

I am trying to install libmodbus on ubuntu 16.04.

I follow the directions in this page.
https://libmodbus.org/download/

I get following error when I run the command

> command: ./configure && make && make install;
>
> error:

```
Making install in src
 /bin/mkdir -p '/usr/local/lib'
 /bin/bash ../libtool   --mode=install /usr/bin/install -c   libmodbus.la '/usr/local/lib'
libtool: install: /usr/bin/install -c .libs/libmodbus.so.5.1.0 /usr/local/lib/libmodbus.so.5.1.0
/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/lib/libmodbus.so.5.1.0': Permission denied
Makefile:414: recipe for target 'install-libLTLIBRARIES' failed
make[2]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
Makefile:617: recipe for target 'install-am' failed
make[1]: *** [install-am] Error 2
Makefile:499: recipe for target 'install-recursive' failed
make: *** [install-recursive] Error 1
```

How to resolve this error ?

Comment: I'm sorry, but was what wrong with installing development package `libmodbus-dev` from [the repository](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libmodbus)?

Comment: Here's your problem: `/usr/bin/install: cannot create regular file '/usr/local/lib/libmodbus.so.5.1.0': Permission denied`. Try running the same commands using sudo one at a time.